# application defined or object defined error - Excel VBA .range(cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of code that is displaying the application defined or object defined error, I have no idea why.

```
filenm17 = "DSR Consolidated"
findstring16 = "21"
```

filenm17 and findstring16 are both defined as strings. I tried removing findstring16 and replacing it with the formula to get findstring16 (it's a cell reference .value) but that still didn't work.

```
Workbooks(filenm17).Sheets("5").Range(Cells(67, findstring16 + 2), _
                               Cells(440, findstring16 + 2)) = firstarray
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a qualifying worksheet, your `Cells()` will refer to the Activesheet: if that isn't "5" then they don't match the `Range()` and that will trigger the error you're getting.

Try:

```
With Workbooks(filenm17).Sheets("5")
    .Range(.Cells(67, CLng(findstring16) + 2), _
           .Cells(440, CLng(findstring16) + 2)).Value = firstarray
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams, I used to use, for example: `Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(10,10))` NOT `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(10,10))` , is that OK? . (ws is the worksheet).

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now!!

Comment: @Fadi - that will work in a regular module, but would fail in a worksheet module for any worksheet other than `ws`, since the scope for an unqualified `Range()` in a worksheet module is always the worksheet itself.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you, I learned new lesson from your comment, very helpful.